# jQuery Mobile - How to allowCrossDomainPages

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a simple jQuery Mobile application that is hosted on one server (server1.com) which includes some php pages that query a database hosted on another server (server2.com).

This all works fine when everything (jQuery Mobile website and Database) is hosted on the same server but when they are separated it doesn't display any of the data. I've been looking at the Configuring Defaults documentation at:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/

and specifically the allowCrossDomainPages option. I've created a new script file called custom-scripting.js which contains the following:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.extend(  $.mobile , {
    allowCrossDomainPages: true
  });
});
```

and the called it as recommended:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

but my PHP page is still not making the request to server2.com. I was hoping that setting allowCrossDomainPages: true would allow the PHP page to make the request to the external server.

Anyone else setup a similar configuration with jQuery Mobile that needs to retrieve data from an external server using php?

Comment: Are you just loading external pages or are you using json to communicate with them?

Comment: My PHP script performs a find on an external database and then I display that data in a jQuery Mobile friendly format (<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true"> etc). As I understand it jQuery Mobile automatically does an AJAX request

Comment: I understand that, I was wondering are you linking directly to some external php file, just on an other domain or are you using classic $.ajax function with json format to access your external php file?

Comment: The PHP file is part of the jQuery Mobile website - it sits on server1 alongside all the other pages that makeup the JQM website. The PHP page does perform a database call against an external database hosted on server2.